# How can I use tidy selection on variables created with `{{ }}`?

Tags: r, dplyr

I create a new variable in a custom function using the `{{ }}` operator, but I can't figure out how to use this newly created variable in a tidy select context, as in the `...` of `separate_rows()`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

foo <- function(col) {
  head(iris) |>
    select({{ col }}) |> 
    mutate("{{ col }}_suffixed" := paste({{ col }}, "SUF")) |> 
    separate_rows(all_of("{{ col }}_suffixed"), sep = " ")
}

foo(Species)
#> Error in `all_of()`:
#> ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> ✖ Column `{{ col }}_suffixed` doesn't exist.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, one could use `contains('_suffixed')`, but that lacks generality, so doesn't really answer the question.

I always wondered why anyone would need `rlang::englue`, but this seems a perfect use case:

```r
foo <- function(col) {
  head(iris) |>
    select({{ col }}) |> 
    mutate("{{ col }}_suffixed" := paste({{ col }}, "SUF")) |> 
    separate_rows(all_of(rlang::englue('{{col}}_suffixed')), sep = " ")
}

foo(Species)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    Species Species_suffixed
#>    <fct>   <chr>           
#>  1 setosa  setosa          
#>  2 setosa  SUF             
#>  3 setosa  setosa          
#>  4 setosa  SUF             
#>  5 setosa  setosa          
#>  6 setosa  SUF             
#>  7 setosa  setosa          
#>  8 setosa  SUF             
#>  9 setosa  setosa          
#> 10 setosa  SUF             
#> 11 setosa  setosa          
#> 12 setosa  SUF
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I also have no recollection of this function while this doesn't feel like a rare workflow

Comment: At last! The perfect way to satisfy all those looking for a tool to make R a macro language.

Comment: @IRTFM …? R *is* fundamentally a macro language. From a language design perspective, that’s basically its entire deal.

Comment: %@KonradRudolph We have different understandings of the term. My understanding derives from Lumley's explication page 11-12 in https://journal.r-project.org/articles/RN-2001-021/RN-2001-021.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the `englue()` workflow you can also construct the new column name using `paste0` and then use regular tidy evaluation:

```r
foo <- function(col) {
  suffixed <- paste0(as.character(substitute(col)), "_suffixed")
  head(iris) |>
    select({{ col }}) |>
    mutate({{ suffixed }} := paste({{ col }}, "SUF")) |>
    separate_rows({{ suffixed }}, sep = " ")
}
```

In this case it’s more code than using `englue()` (and I would recommend using Allan’s answer) but I have to admit that I find it conceptually simpler.

Comment: This is _why_ I wondered what `englue` was for. I would also use something like this IRL.